# Prove that $f^{-1}(\bigcap_{\alpha\in A} E_{\alpha})=\bigcap_{\alpha\in A} f^{-1} (E_a)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

My attempt: $$\text{say}\ x\in f^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{\alpha\in A} E_{\alpha}\right)
\\ \text{This is equivalent to}\ f(x)\in E_{\alpha} \forall \alpha\in A, 
\\\text{Which is equivalent to}\ x\in\bigcap_{\alpha\in A} f^{-1}(E_{\alpha})$$
I'm almost positive that my proof is incorrect, but I don't know why for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of adding additional explanations to your (correct) proof, as [Nate Eldredge](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/822/nate-eldredge) rightly suggests, is to use the calculational proof format designed and advocated by Dijkstra et al., see [EWD1300](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html).  That would make your proof look something like the following.$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\followsfrom}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$

---

For all $\;x\;$,
$$\calc
\tag{*}
    x \in f^{-1}\big[\langle \cap \alpha : \alpha \in A : E_\alpha \rangle\big]
\op\equiv\hint{basic property of $\;{}^{-1}\;$}
    f(x) \in \langle \cap \alpha : \alpha \in A : E_\alpha \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $\;\cap\;$}
\tag{*}
    \langle \forall \alpha : \alpha \in A : f(x) \in E_\alpha \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{basic property of $\;{}^{-1}\;$}
    \langle \forall \alpha : \alpha \in A : x \in f^{-1}[E_\alpha] \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $\;\cap\;$}
\tag{*}    x \in \langle \cap \alpha : \alpha \in A : f^{-1}[E_\alpha] \rangle
\endcalc$$
By set extensionality, this proves the required
$$
f^{-1}\big[\langle \cap \alpha : \alpha \in A : E_\alpha \rangle\big]
\;=\;
\langle \cap \alpha : \alpha \in A : f^{-1}[E_\alpha] \rangle
$$

---

In your version of this proof, you only say that the statements $\ref{*}$ are equivalent, which makes the proof less convincing, and (more importantly) puts a larger burden on the reader who wants to check the correctness of the proof.

Also note that this format shows the nice symmetry in this proof: first we 'unwrap' $\;{}^{-1}\;$ and $\;\cap\;$, and then we 'rewrap' them the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to me, except that the last line should have $x \in$.  If you wish you could add a few more words of explanation to make sure that you completely understand all the step.